# iOS7 start dictation programmatically

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

Is there a way to start dictation feature within my app, without opening the keyboard and pressing microphone button? I would like to add a Button (something like Siri have) to my view and start dictation for `UITextField`.

Is that possible ? I dont mind un-official way, as this app will not end up on AppStore.